# How can we pass the Username, Password from the ubuntu CLI in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How can we pass the Username, Password from the CLI, ie Ubuntu terminal in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor. I have tried running my test using the following `npx cypress-tags run command` but it is not working. Could someone suggest what could be the problem here ? I would like to login with the user/ password passing from CLI

`Cypress version: 8.7.0`

```
CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://one.bookpro.com/main/ npx cypress-tags run -e 'PRO_USERNAME=CypTest2,PRO_PASSWORD=CypTest123' -e TAGS='@login' GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome
```

My `.env` file   has the following

```
CYPRESS_PRO_USERNAME=CypTest1
CYPRESS_PRO_PASSWORD=CypTest123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the package [cypress-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-dotenv)

```js
npm install --save-dev dotenv cypress-dotenv
```

and set up `cypress/plugins/index` like this

```js
const tagify = require('cypress-tags');
const dotenvPlugin = require('cypress-dotenv');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', tagify(config));

  config = dotenvPlugin(config)
  return config
};
```

you can automatically get items added in the `.env` file (check under Setting menu in the Cypress runner).

Same should work with `cypress run` I think.

---

**Note** If you want to have `.env` settings as default, but override on the command line sometimes, the above will not do it.

You need to merge the config as follows

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', tagify(config));

  const fromDotEnv = dotenvPlugin(config)
  config = {
    ...fromDotEnv, // from the .env file
    ...config      // CLI -e PRO_USERNAME=CypTest2,PRO_PASSWORD=CypTest123
  }
  return config
};
```

Also, I had to remove the `'` around the `PRO_USERNAME=CypTest2,PRO_PASSWORD=CypTest123` but that may be an OS issue.

Comment: Thank you I have tried this way after a lot of trial and now it is working for me 
``npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@login',PRO_USERNAME='CypTest2',PRO_PASSWORD='CypTest123'  GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome ``

Comment: I have parameterised the user in Jenkins and confirmed it is picking diff user while running in Jenkins